# Save image in javaFX with applying effects on the image

Tags: image, javafx

I am making an application in JavaFX where the user can upload the photo and apply the effects on it, and in the end, save the image with the effects.

When I save the image, the original image is saved without the effects.
I get the image from the ImagView and save it in the file but the image is saved without the effects.

## **How I can solve this problem and have the picture with the effects that I applied to it?**

The methods below the first one is to apply the effects and the second one is to save the image from ImageView
I need any idea to help me to solve this problem please.

---

```
\\Method of applying the filter
public void applyFilter(){
    SepiaTone sepiaTone = new SepiaTone(cons);
     myImgView.setEffect(sepiaTone);
}
```

```
public void saveImage() throws IOException {

Image imageToBeSaved = myImgView.getImage();// get the image from ImageView
File file = new File("D:/image.png");
        try {
            ImageIO.write (SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(imageToBeSaved,null), "png", file);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: The effects are not applied to the `Image` of the `ImageView`, but to the rendering of the `ImageView` node itself. Using `myImgView.snapshot(...)` and saving the result will probably work for you.